# Transactions not working unless inside DAO

Tags: java, spring, transactions, annotations, dao

I have a problem with transactions in that annotating a service that calls a DAO with @Transactional throws an exception stating that the Session is not open. The only way I can get it working is by annotating the DAO with @Transactional. What on earth can be happening?

This is what I'd like to do but doesn't work:

```
class CustomerService {
    private CustomerDao dao;

    @Transactional
    public void foo() {
        int customerId = dao.getCustomer("fred");
    }
}

class CustomerDao {
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public int getCustomer(String name) {
        String sql = "SELECT {m.*} from Customers {m} where name=:name";
        Query qry = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity("m", Customer.class);
        qry.setParameter("name", name);
        qry.setCacheable(false);
        List<Customer> list = qry.list();
        return list.iterator().next().getId();
    }

    private Session getSession() {
        return hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

This is what I'm doing instead but would rather not have to:

```
class CustomerService {
    private CustomerDao dao;

    public Customer(CustomerDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public void foo() {
        int customerId = dao.getCustomer("fred");
    }
}

class CustomerDao {
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Transactional
    public int getCustomer(String name) {
        String sql = "SELECT {m.*} from Customers {m} where name=:name";
        Query qry = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity("m", Customer.class);
        qry.setParameter("name", name);
        qry.setCacheable(false);
        List<Customer> list = qry.list();
        return list.iterator().next().getId();
    }

    private Session getSession() {
        return hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be caused by the CustomerService being instantiated inside the constructor of a wrapper class, where the wrapper is declared in the Spring xml context file:

```
class AllServices {
    private final CustomerService customerService;
    private final OrderService orderService;

    @Autowired
    public AllServices(CustomerDao customerDao, OrderDao orderDao) {
        this.customerService = new CustomerService(customerDao);
        this.orderService = new OrderService(orderDao);
    }

    public CustomerService getCustomerService() {
        return this.customerService;
    }

    public OrderService getOrderService() {
        return this.orderService;
    }
}
```

The spring file looks like this:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<import resource="classpath:db-spring-conf.xml"/>
<bean id="allServices" class="myPackage.AllServices" />
```

and the db-spring-conf:

```
<bean id="editorDatasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${versioning.db}" />
    <property name="username" value="${versioning.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${versioning.pass}" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="editorTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="editorSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="editorDatasource"/>
    <property name="exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>myPackage.Order</value>
        </list>
    </property> 
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>mappings/customer.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <!-- Enable Query Cache -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <!-- Enable 2nd Level Cache -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="editorHibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="editorSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="editorTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="editorSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- DAOs -->
<bean id="customerDao" class="myPackage.CustomerHibernateDao" />
<bean id="orderDao" class="myPackage.OrderHibernateDao" />
```

I've now moved the instantiation of CustomerService up to the Spring config file and everything works a treat. Do all classes using @Transactional have to be in the context file? Also in order to make it work I had to create an interface for CustomerService to prevent an exception whilst loading the context file - `Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class`

Comment: Perhaps transactional aspect is not applied to `CustomerService`. Show how it's configured.

Comment: show your spring xml config please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you identified the cause of problem - Spring's `@Transactional` support is an aspect, and aspects in Spring are applied only to the components managed by the Spring contrainer (though it [can be changed](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-aspectj), but it's an advanced feature for complex cases).

If you don't like declaring services in XML, you may take a look at other options to delcare Spring-managed components:

- [Classpath scanning](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning)
- [Java-based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) (since Spring 3.x)

Regarding the problem with CGLIB proxies see [7.6 Proxying mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) - probably you don't have CGLIB implementation in the classpath.